# Help with mysql str-to-date

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get this to work. I want to use str_to_date to convert a date string. Here is my insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO cars(carno, color, date) VALUES ('1', 'brown', STR_TO_DATE('$date', 'm%/%d/%Y'))
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? The date in my variable is 12/12/2002

Anyone???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple but yet effective typo, it's `%m` and not `m%`. ;)

Comment: Oh my God!!!!! I cannot even believe I did that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm half blind over here and about an hour and a half later. :)  It worked.

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably just that you interchanged `m%`:

```
"INSERT INTO cars(carno, color, date) VALUES ('1', 'brown', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y'))"
```